# removing schema definitions from xmlelement using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm parsing an object to an xml file. Using UBL Standards.
In some part of the class to serialize, It accepts an XmlElement. But when I set value to this field. When I serialize it, the result file, on this part, It contains the schema definitions again, and no respect of the prefix for the tags.

This is a sample of what I spect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<Invoice    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
            xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
            xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
            xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2"
            xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
            xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
            xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2"
            xmlns:sac="urn:sunat:names:specification:ubl:peru:schema:xsd:SunatAggregateComponents-1"
            xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionContent>
                <sac:AdditionalInformation>
                    <sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
                        <cbc:ID>1001</cbc:ID>
                        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="PEN">348199.15</cbc:PayableAmount>
                    </sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
```

But this is what I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Invoice    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" 
            xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
            xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" 
            xmlns:sac="urn:sunat:names:specification:ubl:peru:schema:xsd:SunatAggregateComponents-1" 
            xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
            xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" 
            xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionContent>
                <AdditionalInformationType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:sac="urn:sunat:names:specification:ubl:peru:schema:xsd:SunatAggregateComponents-1" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns="">
                    <sac:AdditionalProperty>
                        <sac:AdditionalPropertyType xsi:type="sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotalType">
                            <sac:ID>1001</sac:ID>
                            <sac:PayableAmount currencyID="PEN">348199.15</sac:PayableAmount>
                        </sac:AdditionalPropertyType>
```

This is the code I'm using to set the value of the `XmlElement`:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
ContaNet.Ubl.v2.Sac.AdditionalInformationType addInfo = new v2.Sac.AdditionalInformationType();
addInfo.AdditionalProperty.Add(new v2.Sac.AdditionalMonetaryTotalType() { 
    ID = new v2.Cbc.IDType() { 
        Value = "1001",
    },
    PayableAmount = new v2.Cbc.PayableAmountType() {
        CurrencyID = v2.Udt.Enum.CurrencyCodeContentType.PEN,
        Value = Convert.ToDecimal(348199.15)
    }
});

using (XmlWriter xWriter = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild()) {
    new XmlSerializer(addInfo.GetType()).Serialize(xWriter, addInfo);
}

invoice.UBLExtensions = new List<UBLExtensionType>();
UBLExtensionType extType = new UBLExtensionType();
extType.ExtensionContent = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
invoice.UBLExtensions.Add(extType);
```

What is the best way to remove the schema definitions in the XmlElement and force the object serialize using the schemas defined on the top.

This is the way I serialize the object:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
       InvoiceType invoice = GenerateInvoice();
       XmlWriterSettings setting = new XmlWriterSettings();
       setting.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
       setting.Indent = true;
       setting.IndentChars = "\t";
       setting.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
       using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("Invoice.xml", setting)) {
            Type typeToSerialize = typeof(InvoiceType);
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeToSerialize);
            xs.Serialize(writer, invoice);
       }
       Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

The reason of the XmlElement is because there I can store anything

Comment: How do you serialize `Invoice`? And why do you store a content as `XmlElement`? Why not as `AdditionalInformationType`?

Comment: @Yoh Deadfall I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store anything, use `object` and the following code:

```
invoice.UBLExtensions = new List<object>();
invoice.UBLExtensions.Add(addInfo);

Type typeToSerialize = typeof(InvoiceType);
Type[] extraTypes = null;

if (invoice.UBLExtensions != null)
{ extraTypes = invoice.UBLExtensions.Select((e) => e.GetType()).ToArray(); }

// Now the serializer knows all additional types
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeToSerialize, extraTypes);
```

Comment: Not working.. got this error: Not the type expected ContaNet.Ubl.v2.Ext.UBLExtensionType. Use the attribute XmlInclude or SoapInclude to specify the static types.

Comment: Where does you use the `UBLExtensionType` type? In my example there is no `UBLExtensionType`. The `AdditionalInformationType` is inserted directly into `invoice.UBLExtensions`. If `UBLExtensionType` must be used, then add it to `extraTypes` after the `if` statement.